# Geometric interpretation of optimality

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Consider the nonlinear problem 
$$\min_{x\in\Omega} f(x)$$
where $\Omega\subset R^n$ is convex and $f:\Omega\rightarrow R^n$. If $\bar{x}$ is a local min, why is it that $\nabla f(\bar{x})$ is in the dual cone of the set $\Omega - \bar{x}$?

Comment: I know that $\nabla f(\bar{x})$ is in the dual cone of the tangent cone at $\bar{x}$, $T_\Omega(\bar{x})$. I am thinking that maybe the solution is to show that dual cone of $\Omega-\bar{x}$ is a subset of the dual cone of $T_\Omega(\bar{x})$?

Answer (score 0):

Both dual cones coincide.

This can be seen as follows. Let us denote the dual cone by $(\cdot)^+$, the conic hull by $\mathrm{cone}$ and the closure by $\mathrm{cl}$. Then, one has
\begin{align*}
A^+ &= (\mathrm{cone} A )^+, \\
A^+ &= (\mathrm{cl} A )^+, \\
T_\Omega(\bar x) &= \mathrm{cl} \, \mathrm{cone} (\Omega - \bar x).
\end{align*}
Combining these facts, we get the desired
$$
T_\Omega(\bar x)^+ = (\Omega - \bar x)^+.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment $\nabla f(\bar{x})$ is in the tangent cone $T_\Omega(\bar{x})$. However, contrary to the statement in your comment it is left to proof that $T_\Omega(\bar{x})$ is a subset of the dual cone of $\Omega - \bar{x}$. This is, at least geometrically, clear.